# OnPropertyChanged does not trigger getter of getter only property

Tags: android, .net, data-binding, realm, maui

My goal is to trigger GUI changes of a string property (TotalPrice), that only has a getter, of a realm object (Group), its calculus involving properties of related realm objects.

here are some relevant elements of the expected mechanism:

- I change a property (Quantity) of a realm object (Association) in the ContentPage; Quantity is bonded by DataBinding in an Input component.

> <editors:NumericEdit x:Name="QuantityInGroup" CornerRadius="8"
> LabelText="Quantité (groupe)" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
> TextColor="{StaticResource Gray500}"
> TextFontSize="14" BoxHeight="40" HeightRequest="50"
> BoxPadding="10,10,10,5"
> DisplayFormat="0.00   ;(0.00   )"
> Value="{Binding AssociationInGroup.Quantity}">   <---

- Since my TotalPrice is not expected to be saved, I added the realm annotation [Ignored] to TotalPrice, and for testing purposes, I trigger a command from the ContentPage in which I call OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice")

Here is TotalPrice:

```
[Ignored]
public string TotalPrice
{
    get
    {
        if (Associations.Count == 0
            || Associations.Any(asso => asso.ProductPricing is null))
            return null;
        var total = Associations.Sum(asso =>
            asso.ProductPricing!.IsPriced 
                ? asso.ProductPricing.UnitPrice * asso.Quantity <--
                : 0.0);
        return total.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
    }
}
```

- The code which triggers PropertyChanged:

in the ViewModel:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task RemoveAssociationFromGroup()
{
    SelectedGroup.ZePropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
}
```

which calls in the Group class:

```
public void ZePropertyChanged(string name)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(name);
}
```

Actual behavior:
ZePropertyChanged is called, but the getter is not called, and hence the UI is not refreshed. If I exit and enter again in the page, the correct TotalPrice is displayed.

I could add an ObservableProperty to the ViewModel, and calculate TotalPrice manually, but I can't let such an error persist.

I can't use ObservableProperties in the RealmObject because it's a RealmObject already implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

SelectedGroup does contain in a property (Associations) the Association whose Quantity has changed.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

`OnPropertyChanged` is a method invoked by Realm to notify you a property has changed - invoking it will not raise the event. Instead, you should use `RaisePropertyChanged` from within your model:

```
public void ZePropertyChanged(string name)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(name);
}
```

Comment: when RaisePropertyChanged("TotalPrice") is executed, it does not trigger the calculus of TotalPrice.

Comment: Raising the property changed event will not trigger the recalculation by itself. If you have setup your bindings correctly, the binding engine will detect the property has been updated and access the `TotalPrice` property. You haven't posted your binding, so don't know what could be wrong there, but you can verify the `PropertyChanged` event is raised by subscribing to it outside of the binding engine and observing that a property change for `TotalPrice` is indeed emitted.